# SP 2016: application pool account

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, web

I need to change application pool account for SP 2016 web application from farm account to service account, i did the same steps here

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/denotation/2014/02/27/how-to-change-sharepoint-2013-application-pool-account/

the web application isn't browsed with **500 internal error** !!!!!!!!!

Am i missing any permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before changing the account ( following the blog) you have to make sure couple of things.

- New service account should have Database Permission **SPdataAccess** role on the Content Database and Config database. You have to manually set this on the database Server.
- Also make Sure new service account is part of **IIS_IUSRS** group on the server.It is local group...go to computer management > Local User and Groups.
- Reset IIS after changing the App Pool account ( after following Blog steps).

If stil throwing the error, check the event log on the server to get more error information.

Comment: thank you , only  SPdataAccess  , no owner ?!

Comment: if SPdataacess did not work then you can make it DBowner

Comment: no avail, event log An exception occurred when trying to establish endpoint for context: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Extensions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69c3241e6f0468ca' or one of its dependencies. Provider type not defined. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090017).  task category Claims Authentication

Comment: so this is log on as batch right issue...check this to fix it https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24494.sharepoint-2013-an-exception-occurred-when-trying-to-establish-endpoint-for-context-could-not-load-file-or-assembly.aspx

Comment: User needs to be in the local IIS WPG group to run an app pool. Check the event viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow

Have the application pool identities for all farm web applications configured with Logon as batch and Impersonate a client at authentication local rights.
After granting the identities these rights, restart the application pools.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24494.sharepoint-2013-an-exception-occurred-when-trying-to-establish-endpoint-for-context-could-not-load-file-or-assembly.aspx